# How to use youtube data API v3.0 in a meteor.js website?

Tags: javascript, meteor, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm building a website using meteor.js

I've gone through related questions but not able to find much useful information.

I'm looking for a meteor wrapper for the **Youtube data API v3.0** which I can add as a package to my app. If there are no such wrappers available, how can I use the API for searching videos by keywords?

I have already digged through the API documentation very much and I have created API key for my app. I'm not able to figure out how to authenticate my app using javaScript and search for videos.

Please let me know if I'm missing out on providing any information.

Appreciate your help. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use - [renaldo:youtube-api](https://atmospherejs.com/renaldo/youtube-api) package.

For searching youtube create a following server method

```
YoutubeApi.authenticate({
  type: 'key',
  key: 'Your-API-Key'
});

Meteor.methods({
  searchVideo: function(search) {
    YoutubeApi.search.list({
        part: "id",
        type: "video",
        maxResults: 5,
        q: search,
    }, function (err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
    });
  }
});
```

If you want to return data back to client use Futures. For example getting data related to the video by Id.

Add this package (might work without it):

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

and server side:

```
// load future from fibers
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers/future");

Meteor.methods({
  this.unblock();
  var future = new Future();

  getByVideoId: function(id) {
    YoutubeApi.videos.list({
        part: ["snippet", "contentDetails"],
        type: "video",
        maxResults: 1,
        id: id,
    }, function (err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
        future.return({item:data});
    });
    return future.wait();
  }
});
```

Additionally, the official [Youtube documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) is a very useful resource.